# Mod pagespeed: Prevent deferring specific js file

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-pagespeed

I have installed the mod page speed on my whm server with centos , apache.

In the `pagespeed.conf` file i have enabled the `defer_javascript` filter that filter working pretty good.it is defering all js file.

here i want disallow the specific `.js` which i don't want disffer `.js` file in mod pagespeed

suppose i have to disallow defer bellow js

```
example.com/wp-content/plugins/new-royalslider/lib/royalslider/jquery.royalslider.min.js
```

I have tried bellow code but it's not working for me.

```
ModPagespeedDisallow "example.com/wp-content/plugins/new-royalslider/lib/royalslider/jquery.royalslider.min.js"
```

**so how can i disallow defer for specific js is this possible?using ht-access or any other way**

Answer (score 1):

Add the `pagespeed_no_defer=""` attribute to your script tag. See https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/filter-js-defer for more info.